# Recovering Git repository from objects only

Tags: git, data-recovery, disaster-recovery

I have a Windows box which has taken it into it's head to delete most of a Git repository (must have tripped the Important Work Detector ;). All I have left (that I can find) is the objects. I'm not sure how complete the collection of objects is, either. Is it possible to recover things from just the objects? As far as I can tell, the object tree is intact. All the packs and loose objects are in place; I just don't have the metadata to convince Git.

Comment: what do you mean by Just the Objects ?

Comment: Quite literally, this is my repo. `ls repo.git` gives 'objects' only.

Comment: what does this command show `git show -s`

Comment: `fatal: Not a git repository`.

Comment: well it looks like git will not work for you. Ill look into seeing if there is a way to decode the blobs.

Comment: Cheers, Jason. Much appreciated.

Comment: Shows the object tree, plentifully littered with objects. That's all I have. No refs, no logs, nothing but objects.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first thing that I would try is to initialize a new repository with `git init`. Then I'd copy the objects directory from the dead repository into the new repository. Then I'd run `git fsck` in the new repository.

With some luck you'll see a whole lot of dangling objects and with a bit more luck some of the dangling objects will be commit objects which will be the tips of lost branches.

If you run `git show` and/or `git log` on these commits you may be able to recognize some of the branches.

To "recover" them you can just use `git branch` to recreate named branches.

Comment: Awesome! I have one bad SHA-1 file which I need to work out how to rename (Witless renamed it to `e` which isn't helpful), and I need to reattach my HEAD, but that worked excellently. Cheers, Charles!

Comment: I'm not sure how to find the original name of a commit, but reattaching the HEAD was as simple as `git checkout <last-commit-hash>` then creating a `master` branch. Now, I need to find what `00/e` _should_ be.

Comment: @Jashank: If the loose object is valid, you can also “trick” Git into reading it from a (presumably) unrelated loose object pathname (“corruption” demonstrated in [SO5585388](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585388)) and then writing it to the right path. `bash -c 'i=1; while n=$(printf %040x $i) && git cat-file -s "$n" >/dev/null 2>&1; do let i++; done; p=$(printf .git/objects/%.2s/%s "$n" "${n#??}"); echo "using temp object name $n at $p"; set -x; cp -p "$1" "$p" && t=$(git cat-file -t "$n") && git cat-file "$t" "$n" | git hash-object --stdin -t "$t" -w && rm -f "$p"' - .git/objects/00/e`

Comment: @Chris - That's just ... woah. That takes the cake for the best twisted Bash I've ever seen. I _did_ manage to recover the file: Git reported a file deleted from the checkout, so I went hunting, found the file, and moved it in.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already tried `git checkout master`, I'd start with that.

Comment: It can't find a Git repository. "fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount parent ). Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set)."

Answer (score 0):

try using this post

[How to recover Git objects damaged by hard disk failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801577/how-to-recover-git-objects-damaged-by-hard-disk-failure)

that answer may have some *nix related info. Let me know if it helps.

Ill see what it does.

Comment: it looks like the first couple commands may be helpful. It shows you how to unpack the pack folder from the objects

Comment: Yeah, I'll take that for a spin. Do I need to init a new Git repo now?

Comment: probably not. I would recommend backing up what you have so you dont lose any more. I gotta run for now. Ill check back in when I get back.

Comment: I don't think that this is the optimal approach. There's no evidence that objects have been damaged so unpacking and recovering objects shouldn't be necessary. It should be enough to recover the objects - packed or loose - into a working git repository and going from there.

Comment: If you have examples of how to do that I will be more then willing to put them up