# Recovering git repository from the objects directory

Tags: git

I don't know how it happened, but I had a data loss and was only left with a `.git` directory containing only an `objects` directory.

I've followed the steps from [Recovering Git repository from objects only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767593/recovering-git-repository-from-objects-only):

1. Created a new directory and ran `git init`
2. Copied the `objects` directory I had to the new `.git/objects` directory
3. Ran `git fsck` command.

The output of the above steps produced the following msg:

```
notice: HEAD points to an unborn branch (master)
notice: No default references
dangling commit 0b2c7d52b6a7e6d4e2858e9ebf207c315407c87c
dangling commit 8dceafea1634c923069f6d4b925839c28d92c4e5
dangling commit dd7bdd04c557a018c15fd0948075121f181decd1
```

When I try to run `git log` at this stage I get `fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'`.

What should I do in order to recover my data???

---

EDIT:

klaustopher's suggestion:

1. I added a file under `/refs/heads` called `master` containing one of the dangling commits.
2. The msg I got in return was `fatal: unable to read tree 3c864da48b16ad0dc5f8ae585380270a708a1e56`
3. I checked and there is no 3c directory under "objects"...

Answer (score 1):

Well, you got the objects but git has no idea which is the commit it should interpret as the master. There are three suggestions in the output of `git fsck`. You could try the following:

- create the `.git/refs/heads` directory and create a file called `master`
- Put the SHA1 hash of one of the commits in this file
- Run `git checkout master`

If that is not the commit you were looking for, put in another sha1 hash in the `master`-file

--

**Edit**: If those aren't real commits like you described in the comment, than you should maybe go through your objects. With `git show 2452845a7b526db3dfbf88c1c2ca05967ef9653a` you can see the contents of the file. If it is a commit it will start with the word `commit` and also have the date, commit message, etc in it. You could maybe write a little shell script to go through all the objects. When you found your commit, put its sha1 in the refs/heads/master file and do what I described above

Comment: I am trying to do this, but now there is something totally strange.. I make a complete new directory and run "git init". When I then run "git log" i get error "fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'"... That is a completely different directory, looks like git is broken now

Comment: When I go to the new directory and /refs/heads/ there is no master file for some reason :/

Comment: Yeah, there is no master, since there's no real commit. Create the directory and create the file

Comment: I added some more info to my post regarding you suggestion. Do you have any inputs?

Comment: I added a way how you can find your commits .. Not a nice one, but a possible one