# Git - folder "refs" missing

Tags: git

I had to recover a few git bare repositories from a backup, and found out that git (I am using msysgit on wondows XP) did not recognise the repo as such. After some investigation, I found the problem seems to be that the folder "refs" was missing, together with the subfolders "heads" and "remotes". I also do not have the file "heads/master". Is there any way I can re-create it? I really need to recover the data in these folders.

Comment: how about just `clone` repository again? Or you can `init` new repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, if you have any checkouts of these repos, the easiest thing to do is to just recover from those.

---

`refs` just contains files with the SHA1 of commits that those names point to; `refs/heads/master` is probably all you need, containing just the SHA1 of the commit for HEAD. You didn't lose any data (that's all in `objects`), but it might be a bit tricky to find out the SHA1 of the commits you want.

If you have the file `logs/HEAD`, the ref should be in there at the bottom (the first SHA1 being the parent of the most recent commit and the second being the id of it; there might be more if it's a merge commit, not sure). For example, here's the last line of one of my repos:

```
4b2ef6873c3f4c7eaebca06fee4b95ffa9cf58c3 feb84419b6685b920f8a3d61a77e9508ba5dcfe1 Dougal Sutherland <dougal@gmail.com> 1342838724 -0400 pull: Fast-forward
```

so the hash starting with `feb84419b6` is the one I'd want. Unfortunately, I think these are only in non-bare checkouts.

If you don't have those logs, the commits are all in the `objects` directory. It's somewhat likely to be a recently modified one, which you can get on Unix for example by `ls -1t */* | head -10` from the `objects` directory; you can try a couple and see what happens. If you get from this, say

```
04/718652eb1f03bb0594cc05665665b749b52a87
```

then remove the `/` to get the hash you want to use:

```
04718652eb1f03bb0594cc05665665b749b52a87
```

Comment: I have no **logs** folder. I only have **hooks**, **info** and **objects**. I am not sure if this is because this is a mirror repository, but does it mean I am out of luck? Any other place where I can get the SHA1 of the last commit?

Comment: @LittleFish Does it work if you use the name of the most-recently-modified object?

Comment: @Dougal, The problem is that I do not know which one is the most recently-modified. I just tried, but all the files under objects have the same time-stamp

Comment: OK, with some tips from here, I managed to find the post [Recovering Git Repository from objects only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767593/recovering-git-repository-from-objects-only). Because I had only few commits, it was easy to get the right one from git fsck. Then I did as you suggested to get that SHA1 into the .git/refs/heads/master file, and it worked!!!!Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

If you lost all your references (refs folder), but don't lose any actual data you can find all **possible** last commits by finding dangling commits (i.e commits which are not referenced by other commits as parents)

You can do it with the help of this command

```
git fsck --lost-found
```

This lists all dangling commits (and probably some other useful information).
Use

```
git log SHA1SUM
```

to investigate further.
Also it is a good idea to run

```
git fsck
```

to make sure that only referenced where lost.

**UPD:** Also refs can be located in **packed-refs** file.