How to migrate old git repos that are no longer recognized as git repos?
I've just found that I have several old Git repos that have not been modified in the current decade — and these are no longer recognized as Git repos.
One of the unrecognized repos contains the files:
drwxr-xr-x  13 jleffler  staff   416 Nov 20  2021 .git
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff    25 Nov 22  2015 .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff    23 Oct 29  2015 .git/HEAD
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff    41 Nov 21  2015 .git/ORIG_HEAD
-rwxr--r--   1 jleffler  staff   137 Oct 29  2015 .git/config
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff    73 Oct 29  2015 .git/description
drwxr-xr-x  11 jleffler  staff   352 Oct 29  2015 .git/hooks
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jleffler  staff   452 Oct 29  2015 .git/hooks/applypatch-msg.sample
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jleffler  staff   896 Oct 29  2015 .git/hooks/commit-msg.sample
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jleffler  staff   189 Oct 29  2015 .git/hooks/post-update.sample
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jleffler  staff   398 Oct 29  2015 .git/hooks/pre-applypatch.sample
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jleffler  staff  1642 Oct 29  2015 .git/hooks/pre-commit.sample
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jleffler  staff  1356 Oct 29  2015 .git/hooks/pre-push.sample
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jleffler  staff  4951 Oct 29  2015 .git/hooks/pre-rebase.sample
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jleffler  staff  1239 Oct 29  2015 .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg.sample
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jleffler  staff  3611 Oct 29  2015 .git/hooks/update.sample
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   377 Mar 24  2017 .git/index
drwxr-xr-x   4 jleffler  staff   128 May  3  2016 .git/info
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   240 Oct 29  2015 .git/info/exclude
-rw-------   1 jleffler  staff    59 May  3  2016 .git/info/refs
drwxr-xr-x   4 jleffler  staff   128 May  3  2016 .git/logs
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff     0 May  3  2016 .git/logs/HEAD
drwxr-xr-x   3 jleffler  staff    96 Oct 29  2015 .git/logs/refs
drwxr-xr-x   3 jleffler  staff    96 May  3  2016 .git/logs/refs/heads
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff     0 May  3  2016 .git/logs/refs/heads/master
drwxr-xr-x   4 jleffler  staff   128 May  3  2016 .git/objects
drwxr-xr-x   3 jleffler  staff    96 May  3  2016 .git/objects/info
-rw-------   1 jleffler  staff    54 May  3  2016 .git/objects/info/packs
drwxr-xr-x   4 jleffler  staff   128 May  3  2016 .git/objects/pack
-r--r--r--   1 jleffler  staff  2024 May  3  2016 .git/objects/pack/pack-9f36e2555a3014c30b8ca6b3594b4c20aec9e723.idx
-r--r--r--   1 jleffler  staff  7200 May  3  2016 .git/objects/pack/pack-9f36e2555a3014c30b8ca6b3594b4c20aec9e723.pack
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff    98 May  3  2016 .git/packed-refs

The content of the .git/config file is:
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true

Running git status yields:
$ git status
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
$

Another directory which is still recognized as a repo contains the files:
drwxr-xr-x  15 jleffler  staff     480 Jun  2 16:22 .git
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff     228 Oct 26  2017 .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff     206 Oct 21  2017 .git/FETCH_HEAD
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff      23 Jan 18  2017 .git/HEAD
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff      41 Oct 21  2017 .git/ORIG_HEAD
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff     307 Jan 18  2017 .git/config
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff      73 Jan 18  2017 .git/description
drwxr-xr-x  12 jleffler  staff     384 Jan 18  2017 .git/hooks
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jleffler  staff     478 Jan 18  2017 .git/hooks/applypatch-msg.sample
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jleffler  staff     896 Jan 18  2017 .git/hooks/commit-msg.sample
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jleffler  staff     189 Jan 18  2017 .git/hooks/post-update.sample
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jleffler  staff     424 Jan 18  2017 .git/hooks/pre-applypatch.sample
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jleffler  staff    1642 Jan 18  2017 .git/hooks/pre-commit.sample
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jleffler  staff    1348 Jan 18  2017 .git/hooks/pre-push.sample
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jleffler  staff    4951 Jan 18  2017 .git/hooks/pre-rebase.sample
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff     544 Jan 18  2017 .git/hooks/pre-receive.sample
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jleffler  staff    1239 Jan 18  2017 .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg.sample
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jleffler  staff    3610 Jan 18  2017 .git/hooks/update.sample
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   13334 Jun  2 16:09 .git/index
drwxr-xr-x   4 jleffler  staff     128 Nov 11  2018 .git/info
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff     240 Jan 18  2017 .git/info/exclude
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff     641 Nov 11  2018 .git/info/refs
drwxr-xr-x   4 jleffler  staff     128 Nov 11  2018 .git/logs
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff       0 Nov 11  2018 .git/logs/HEAD
drwxr-xr-x   4 jleffler  staff     128 Jan 18  2017 .git/logs/refs
drwxr-xr-x   3 jleffler  staff      96 Nov 11  2018 .git/logs/refs/heads
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff       0 Nov 11  2018 .git/logs/refs/heads/master
drwxr-xr-x   3 jleffler  staff      96 Jan 18  2017 .git/logs/refs/remotes
drwxr-xr-x   4 jleffler  staff     128 Nov 11  2018 .git/logs/refs/remotes/origin
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff       0 Nov 11  2018 .git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff       0 Nov 11  2018 .git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/master
drwxr-xr-x   4 jleffler  staff     128 Nov 11  2018 .git/objects
drwxr-xr-x   3 jleffler  staff      96 Nov 11  2018 .git/objects/info
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff      54 Nov 11  2018 .git/objects/info/packs
drwxr-xr-x   4 jleffler  staff     128 Nov 11  2018 .git/objects/pack
-r--r--r--   1 jleffler  staff    8660 Nov 11  2018 .git/objects/pack/pack-d5c4ff545cf0c5c55c767d2d20a5a947fc9e980e.idx
-r--r--r--   1 jleffler  staff  117736 Nov 11  2018 .git/objects/pack/pack-d5c4ff545cf0c5c55c767d2d20a5a947fc9e980e.pack
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff     621 Nov 11  2018 .git/packed-refs
drwxr-xr-x   3 jleffler  staff      96 Nov 20  2021 .git/refs
drwxr-xr-x   3 jleffler  staff      96 Jan 18  2017 .git/refs/remotes
drwxr-xr-x   3 jleffler  staff      96 Nov 11  2018 .git/refs/remotes/origin
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff      32 Jan 18  2017 .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD

The .git/config file contains:
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:jleffler/scc-snapshots
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master

And the output from git status is:
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

I'm not sure what the significant differences are.

Can you identify what the problem is?
Is there a way to fix it short of downloading an old version of Git, building it, and running it?
Would that even fix the problem — or would I just have to rebuild the history one check-in at a time, copying between the old repo using the old Git and a new repo built using the current system-provided Git?

I don't know if it is significant, but I'm now running on a MacBook Pro with an Apple M2 Pro chip, running macOS Sonoma 14.5.  When the repos were created, I was using MacBook Pro machines with Intel chips.  I doubt if it matters, but I'm now using zsh as my shell where I was previously using bash.
The current version of Git is /usr/bin/git which reports the version "git version 2.39.3 (Apple Git-146)".

I don’t think it being old is necessarily the issue. Git (badly) prints out the same message when there are permission problems that stop it from recognizing the repo. Is this in a protected directory? Try using Archive Utility to zip the directory, send it to a basic Linux system, and check git status there.

I'm no expert but to my eye the lack of a .git/refs directory seems diagnostic. With neither heads nor remotes the repo is effectively empty of reachable data. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604526/git-folder-refs-missing

And see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767593/recovering-git-repository-from-objects-only. Basically, you can make just enough of a .git/refs/heads entry to get this thing working, manually, pretty easily.

@Ry-: I'll update the question when I've done some investigative work, but…  I have a "work" machine and a "home" machine.  The problem I've got was found on the home machine. The $HOME/src directories are (deliberately) very similar — and at least one of the directories on the work machine is OK where the directory on the home isn't.  The .git/index files are different.  I need to complete the cross-machine checking, but it looks as though I effectively have a working backup.  I also have access to (work) Linux machines from the work machine — I can look at copying back and forth.

@matt —  Thank you.  I'll look at those other questions.  I think the absent refs may be simply because the repo without them has never been cloned to another machine (so the only place that editing has occurred is on the local machine), whereas the working one has been 'cloned' (see the remote entries in the .git/config file).

Try git init foo to initialize a local repo foo and copy .git/objects/* recursively from the bad .git to foo/.git. Run git commands in foo to check if it's okay.

@matt: Using git fsck sounds promising, but when I try it, I get the dreaded "fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git" message.  So that isn't part of the answer.

"I think the absent refs may be simply because the repo without them has never been cloned to another machine" But for that to be so, you would have needed to make at least one branch. Where is it? That is what you would find in refs/heads if it existed.

@matt — I get the impression you are probably right — the missing refs is the cause of the trouble.  I'm not sure how that could have gotten screwed up.  I don't recall doing anything that might have moved stuff around en masse.  Fortunately, it looks as though I can copy the repos from the "work" machine to my "home" machine.  The alternative would be to use Time Machine and (try to) find out when the change occurred.  That might be an exercise in futility if the change occurred before I got my new "home" machine — and the new backup sequence started.

It seems to me that perhaps the problematic repo was intended as a bare repo: it used to live on a server and was just copied to your computer rather than being cloned. If so, then you can solve the whole problem just by cloning it now. (For the difference in structure between a local repo and a bare repo, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49627104/341994)

I'm going to suggest a very simple-minded solution. Let's suppose what you're looking at is a bare repository that has been stripped of its refs directory. Then you can fix the problem like this:

Manually, give the troublesome .git directory a refs subdirectory.
Manually, give that refs subdirectory a heads subdirectory and a tags subdirectory.


These directories will be empty. Nevertheless, this should be sufficient to get Git to see this as a Git repository; and you can easily test this hypothesis.
If that doesn't work, no harm done; just remove the heads subdirectory again. If it does work, then make a new empty folder somewhere else, cd into it, and say
git clone /path/to/that/.git

The result will be a usable working tree.

I enacted this scenario on my machine and it worked, on the assumption that the problematic repo is (as supposed here) a bare repository without a refs directory. But I have no way of knowing if that assumption is correct for your repo, so this might not work for you.
